# Regression with percentile independent variable

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata, quantiles

I am running a simple regression with average standardized exam scores at the school-level, and weekly household income at the neighborhood-level where the school is located.

The two variables look as follows, where the average standardized exam scores are scored out of a 100.

```
dataex avg_score avg_hh_inc
61.62         400
69.11         1000
66.67         700
61.26         300
56.79         250
64.02         400
68.15         1200
 61.7         130
```

I wanted to know if creating a quantile variable for household income, where we end up with five separate groups empirically makes sense or do we lose information by doing that?

I have created a quantile income variable as follows:

```
xtile binned=avg_hh_inc, nq(5)
tabstat avg_hh_inc, by(binned) s(n min max)
rename binned quantiles_avg_hh_inc
```

I then ran two OLS models, with one main difference. The first model presented below uses avg_hh_inc in its continuous form without splitting the data into 5 percentile groups.

```
regress average avg_hh_inc c.male c.gini_region c.average_unemp c.college_share c.consumption_to_inc if curriculum_track=="scientifi
> c" & exam_type=="achievement" //i.region_dummy //i.city_dummy

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =       693
-------------+----------------------------------   F(6, 686)       =     29.56
       Model |   11490.946         6  1915.15767   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  44444.2816       686  64.7875825   R-squared       =    0.2054
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1985
       Total |  55935.2276       692  80.8312538   Root MSE        =    8.0491

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           average |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  avg_hh_inc       |   .0021996   .0009228     2.38   0.017     .0003877    .0040114
              male |  -7.426205   .6173315   -12.03   0.000    -8.638291   -6.214119
       gini_region |   .3441247   .1483134     2.32   0.021     .0529221    .6353274
     average_unemp |   -.231201   .1265314    -1.83   0.068    -.4796362    .0172343
     college_share |  -.1327362   .2103539    -0.63   0.528     -.545751    .2802785
consumption_to_inc |  -40.45142   20.04081    -2.02   0.044    -79.80011   -1.102735
             _cons |   101.8783   18.09396     5.63   0.000      66.3521    137.4045
```

Again, the main difference here is i.quantiles_avg_hh_inc. However, the main differences I noticed with the results were:

1- explanatory power of the model rises a bit below, with an Adj R^2 at  0.2107, from  0.1985 in the first model,
2-Using avg_hh_inc as a continuous independent variable in the first model produces a statistically significant result, whereas splitting the data into percentiles results in only the 3rd quantile having a coefficient that is statistically significant.

```
regress average i.quantiles_avg_hh_inc c.male c.gini_region c.average_unemp c.college_share c.consumption_to_inc if curriculum_track
> =="scientific" & exam_type=="achievement" //i.region_dummy i.city_dummy

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =       693
-------------+----------------------------------   F(9, 683)       =     21.53
       Model |  12362.4578         9  1373.60642   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  43572.7698       683  63.7961491   R-squared       =    0.2210
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2107
       Total |  55935.2276       692  80.8312538   Root MSE        =    7.9872

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   average |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
quantiles_avg_hh_inc       |
                        2  |  -1.877046   1.294038    -1.45   0.147    -4.417817    .6637238
                        3  |    3.25386   1.398788     2.33   0.020     .5074188    6.000302
                        4  |   2.350357   1.527435     1.54   0.124    -.6486751    5.349389
                        5  |   1.342123   1.039865     1.29   0.197    -.6995918    3.383838
                           |
                      male |  -7.194683   .6143532   -11.71   0.000    -8.400931   -5.988435
               gini_region |   .3376579   .1598689     2.11   0.035     .0237645    .6515514
             average_unemp |   .0321536   .1435789     0.22   0.823    -.2497553    .3140626
             college_share |  -.2991404   .2395885    -1.25   0.212    -.7695589    .1712781
        consumption_to_inc |  -67.91695   21.15152    -3.21   0.001    -109.4468   -26.38714
                     _cons |   131.2151   19.53605     6.72   0.000     92.85715     169.573
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Finally, one concern I had with splitting the income variable into percentiles is that the data are split unequally into five groups, which I assume is wrong?

````
tab quantiles_medpricesqmsmall

5 quantiles |
         of |
medpricesqm |
      small |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |        405       21.96       21.96
          2 |        333       18.06       40.02
          3 |        610       33.08       73.10
          4 |        134        7.27       80.37
          5 |        362       19.63      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,844      100.00
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by discretizing continuous variables you are losing information. The R^2 apparently increases because you a re fitting 5 parameters instead of just one. For modeling purposes the important assumptions is that your independent variable has a linear effect on your dependent variable, which I would expect income does not have. I would suggest to

1. fit the regression and look at the residuals to see if the linearity assumption holds.
2. Add some nonlinear terms to your regression like the income^2 and income^3
3. you can also try to take a log of the income and use that in your regression. both of these options are better than dichotomizing